# Django query optimization with a ManytoMany Field

Tags: django

I found that this one bit of code (in bold) in my template produces ~250 queries and makes things REALLY slow:

```
{% for part in latestupdates %}
{{ part }}
      **{% for unipart in part.uniparts.all|slice:":5" %}**
      <tr>
        <td>
            <p style ="font-size:12px;"><a href = "/spices/{{ unipart_id }}/view_part">{{ unipart.part }}</a></p></td>
        <td><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/company_logos/thumbs/{{part.model.all.0.manufacturer}}.jpg" alt="{{part.model.all.0.manufacturer}} {{unipart.part}}" height="24" width='115' /></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The relationship between Unipart and Part is as follows:

```
class UniPart (models.Model):
    model = models.ManyToManyField (Part, related_name = 'uniparts')
```

My view is as follows:

`latestupdates = Part.objects.all().order_by('-added')`

Basically what I want to is get 5 Unipart objects that link to Part. But this is costing me big time!!! What is a more efficient way to do than what I did? I actually have >600 database queries which is pretty pathetic and I'm reading up on database optimization but for this bit I can't find anything relevant. Help! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) the method of QuerySet.

```
latestparts = Part.objects.all().prefetch_related('uniparts').order_by('-added')
```

But pay attention on amount of items you trying to prefetch. Because it can overwlow you memory.

And yes this works only in `django 1.4` I think.

Use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) if you have `models.ForeignKey` field (not your case). This works in older version of django.

Comment: I have Django 1.3! Is there an alternative?

Comment: There is no an easy way. You can prefetch it you self. All you can do is to make two queries and then connect them in python by ids. But this is crazy work. You need to be very careful to not overhelm your memory.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try updating to 1.4 and see what happens. If my app doesn't break, I'll try out what you suggested. Thanks and stay tuned for an update!

Comment: If you boss. Just upgrade django and be hapy.

Comment: Thanks just upgraded. It reduced the queries by about 50! But just curious -- do I reference it the same way as above? ie. `part.uniparts.all` or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your last question. But you are not making any query when you do .all() or .filter() QuerySet object contain jus query in it (it is lazy), and it's executes only when you need it (for example: when you iterate through it). SO keep it in mind. So, if you need to use your query set multiple times in one request you would need to make query by takin it in list `list( queryset.all() )`. But keep in mind this could cause overhelm of memory.